# Opencart: Upgrading through git

Tags: git, opencart

Does anyone have experience upgrading Opencart completely or partially through git with the latest code here: https://github.com/opencart/opencart?

I'd like to be able to just pull the code down into a branch, run the install, and then merge the installed root into my master branch.  Is this feasible to attempt?  Would it work how I want?

*UPDATE:
So I tried out this method and had pretty good results.  If I knew git better I could maybe automate this a little better.

I copied over everything in a new branch. Did the upgrade.
Merged into dev manually on the files I had changed outside of theme.  *lengthy but I'm not sure how to or if I could do it better through git
Then merged that back into master when I had tested it.

Took a while but did what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong on this approach.

Just make sure Your dev branch is the same as master before upgrading. Then after installing the upgrade (due to possible DB changes) test the dev and make sure everything is working as supposed to. After a green lights You are free to merge dev into the master branch.

Nice idea though!

Answer (score 1):

As shadyyx said you can do this all in a development branch.

You could use a similar branch method as gitflow, make a dev branch, then branch from this. Your master will remain stable. You can install on the branch off the development branch, then test the merge into your development branch.

Then once that branch is tested and you are happy you can remove your branch from development. You can merge any changes or hotfixes from master into your development branch and once fully tested your development branch will contain the most up to date instance. You can then seamlessly merge this back to your master branch and put it live.

See the following for example on setting up the branching model: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/